# Labeling image frames that have binary class

Tags: python

I have some tiff face images where i am trying to label them with 0s and 1s. By order, the first 50 frames will always belong to class 0 and the next 150 will always belong to class 1. But i am using `os.walk` so i read every image folder inside that directory, therefore i will have a repeat of fifty 0s and a hundred and fifty 1s, as i have many face images.

Loading images:

```
import os
def getimages(path):
    loadedImages = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            image_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            arr = np.array(name)
            loadedImages.append(arr)
    return loadedImages


my_images = np.asarray(getimages('C:/Users/Images/'))
X = my_images
```

my_images outputs an array of size (1600,)

I did try something, it did make sense to me at first, but it doesn't work.

```
    class_1 = 150
    class_0 = 50
y = []
for i in range(0, 8):
    for idx in range(1):
        y.extend( [idx]*sober_amount)
        for idx in range(1):
            y.extend([idx+1]*drunk_amount)
    
y = np.array(y)
print(y[0:251])
```

Basically i want to generate a vector that always labels the first 50 images it finds to class 0 and next 150 images it'll label them to class 1

Comment: Think carefully about what the value passed to `extend` should look like. You want it to have a bunch of elements that are all the same, yes? In a single one of these sequences, what is the rule that tells you what the value should be? What is the rule that tells you how many copies there should be? First, make it correctly produce a single run of 0s followed by a single run of 1s. Next, think about a rule that tells you how many times to alternate.

Comment: I edited my question with a solution that i came up with, but i wanted it to dynamically label as it readed images. Because basically it'll read 200 images per folder, in resulting in 1600 images

Comment: In case it had like 49 images, it'll would enumerate fourty nine 0s